# How to do a specialization in CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first

How can I do specialization in CodeFirst? Like this:

https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/lectures/images/specialization_vehicle.gif

Tried to find it, but haven't any success. I'm building the database for my mv4 internet application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three options to do that,

1. [TPT -table per type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)
   *Table per Type is about representing inheritance relationships as relational foreign key associations. Every class/subclass that declares persistent properties—including abstract classes—has its own table*. Basically you will have one table for each entity in the hierachy.
2. [TPH - Table per hierachy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)
   *Enable polymorphism by denormalizing the SQL schema, and utilize a type discriminator column that holds type information*. Basically you will have one table for the hierarchy of your entities
3. [TPC Table per concrete type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)
   *In Table per Concrete type (aka Table per Concrete class) we use exactly one table for each (nonabstract) class*. You will have one table for each concrete type in the hierarchy.

   For more details read the articles given in the links.Your next question will be what is the best method. I think it's dependent on your domain and the amount of data and columns you have for each entity. And also you will need to think about the performance and maintainability. [Here is a good article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx) for you to make the decision .